# Graphql Apollo Server Resolver: set of arguments for field and nested object

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

I am looking at this example in graphql docs:

```
{
  human(id: "1000") {
    name
    height(unit: FOOT)
  }
}
```

So, I'd like to built my schema and resolvers the way, that way that I can query similar.
I have a list of Tacos :

```
const tacos = [
    {
      cathegory: 'meat',
      type: 'Al Pastor',
      like: false
    },
    {
      cathegory: 'meat',
      type: 'Barbacoa',
      like: false
    },
    {
      cathegory: 'meat',
      type: 'Chorizo',
      like: true
    },

  
    {
      cathegory: 'fish',
      type: 'Camaron',
      like: true
    },
    {
      cathegory: 'fish',
      type: 'Salmon',
      like: false
    },
    {
      cathegory: 'fish',
      type: 'Pulpo',
      like: false
    },

    {
      cathegory: 'veggi',
      type: 'Cauliflower',
      like: true
    },
    {
      cathegory: 'veggi',
      type: 'Avocado',
      like: true
    },
    {
      cathegory: 'veggi',
      type: 'Tofu',
      like: false
    },
]
```

My schema is super simple:

```
const typeDefs = gql`
  type Taco {
    cathegory: String
    type: String
    like: Boolean
  }

type Query {
  tacos(cathegory: String, like: Boolean): [Taco]
}
`;
```

I managed to write my resolver so that I cant filter according to the cathegory:

```
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    tacos: (parent, args, context, info) => {
      return tacos.filter((taco) => taco.cathegory === args.cathegory);
    },
  },
};
```

So I can query as follows

```
query xyz {
  tacos(cathegory:"veggi" ) {
  like
}
}
```

But how can I write my resolver, so that I can query only veggi tacos where like is true? I am super new to this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    tacos: (parent, args, context, info) => {
      return tacos.filter((taco) => {
        if(Reflect.has(args, 'like')) {
          return taco.cathegory === args.cathegory && taco.like === args.like;
        }
        return taco.cathegory === args.cathegory;
      });
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: Is it possible not to hardcode the cathegory in resolver? I only need to define which cathegory I'd like to query in query itself.

Comment: I'd need to query like this: `query getAllMeatTacosILike {tacos(cathegory:"meat") {type like(like:true)}}` and get back only "tacos": [{ "type": "Chorizo","like": true}], but this for all three cathegoris I have, not only veggi

Comment: `return tacos.filter((taco) => taco.cathegory === args.cathegory && taco.like === args.like); ` this worked

Comment: you don't need const cond anymore, right?

Comment: also, please double check the syntax, some brackets are missing. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236053/discussion-between-katharina-schreiber-and-fraction).